# What is wrong with my program?

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I cannot figure out what is wrong. I spent a few hours trying to debug this. I am compiling with gcc -m32 source.c -o source

How else can I approach this when debugging? Right now, I am isolating the code in many different ways and everything is working the way I expect but its working the wrong way when I have it all together.

This program takes an input and then looks for the highest position with the 1 bit.

I removed my code for now.

Comment: Try stepping through the code under gdb to see what's going on in the registers etc.

Comment: can you tell us what is wrong: what number did you input ? what does the program output ? what did you expect for an output ?

Comment: this code doesn't compile with `gcc -m32`: `undefined reference to _num` and `_position`. Please clean up before posting.

Comment: I have never used that before. How can I use gdb to check registerS?

Comment: @Mat You have to remove the `_` for num and position. Mac OS X requires underscores.

@Andrien When I input 1, I am expect `bit positon: 1`, but it is jumping to `noones:` and outputting `no ones`

Comment: please do that yourself. edit your post to make the example compilable. and remove all the extraneous stuff while at it.

Comment: @Mat Sure, no problem, but wouldn't a mac user say the opposite? :D

Comment: When you fix this problem, be sure to test that you can detect an input of 1.  I think there might be another bug there...

Comment: @Michael Burr Definitely. I'll update with results.

Comment: @Michael Burr Wow, there is a bug at 1.

Comment: @Michael THANK YOU! I changed 31 to 32 and it worked. You were right on the spot.

Comment: Although probably not the point of this homework-style question, but this can be done without a loop by using the BSR instruction.

Comment: @ohmantics What is BSR instruction?

Comment: @Doug if you're working on x86 assembler it's a good idea to get a reference book.  Also, just use `__builtin_clz` for GCC and `_BitScanReverse` for Windows.

Comment: @Doug what Steve-o said. Apparently SO doesn't allow LMGTFY links, but search Google for "bsr intel instruction".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in bitsearch, you are storing `num` in `eax`, you store a special value in `edx` in order to perform `check`. `check` is testing if the highest bit is set (indicating a negative number), and exits if its the case...

the `andl` instruction in `check` stores the result of the operation inside the second operand (`eax`), so the result overwrites `num`.

then in `zero` you are using `edx` to perform your computation... `edx` contains the special value of the start of the function, so your result will always be wrong.

now at the end of `zero`, you are going back to `check`, but the check is unnecessary here, you should loop back to `zero`instead...

Comment: Simply change the `andl` instruction to `testl` to avoid trashing `eax`.

Comment: ho that's more complicated... i was asking myself: why `check`and why `2147483648` ? `check` is simply removing the sign, so ignore my comment about `andl` overwriting `num`. all is left is that `edx` should be `eax` at the beginning of `zero`...

Comment: I did not know `and1` trashes `eax`. I thought it was just a harmless comparison. I am going to test that right now.

Comment: i completed my answer regarding the loop. don't forget to use `eax` instead of `edx` in the first ine of `zero`...

Comment: I just wanted to tell you THANK YOU! I learned that `addl` overwrites the register. THANK YOU!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Does the bit-search need to be implemented in assembly?  A simple `for` loop can accomplish the same task, and is much more readable:

```
int num = 10;
int maxFound = -1;
for (int numShifts = 0; numShifts < 32 && num != 0; numShifts++) {
    if ((num & 1) == 1) {
        maxFound = numShifts;
    }
    num = num >> 1;
}
//the last position that had a 1 will be in maxFound
```

Comment: also, `position = (int)(log(num)/log(2))` is way shorter, but that's simply not what the OP asked for. what if the OP really wants assembly ? (imagine the C code around is just boilerplate to provide a test case)

Comment: Yeah, it has to be in assembly, but thumbs up for helping!

Comment: @Adrien That's interesting how you use logs. I have never used logs in programming and its very foreign to me, but I am still an undergrad.

Comment: in short, the logarithm (`log()`) function is the inverse of the exponent (`pow()`). so (approximately), if `pow(x, y) == n`, then `log(n, x) == y`. unfortunately, the C runtime library does not provide a 2 arguments log, it provides only a "natural logarithm". but mathematics says that `log(x, y) == log(x)/log(y)`, hence the formula above... now why use `2` for the value of `y`: a binary number is composed of "bits", which are powers of two...

Answer (score 1):

There's a neat bit-fiddling trick: x & -x isolates the last 1-bit. The following C program uses a lookup table based on de Bruijn sequences to compute the number of trailing (!) zeros of a number in constant (!) time:

```
unsigned int x;  // find the number of trailing zeros in 32-bit x
int r;           // result goes here
int table[32] = 
{
  0, 1, 28, 2, 29, 14, 24, 3, 30, 22, 20, 15, 25, 17, 4, 8, 
  31, 27, 13, 23, 21, 19, 16, 7, 26, 12, 18, 6, 11, 5, 10, 9
};
r = table[((uint32_t)((x & -x) * 0x077CB531U)) >> 27];
```

Doing this in assembly language (which I stopped learning by the age of 16) should be no problem. Now all you have to do is to reverse the bits in num and apply the technique described above.

I wrote a paper about the trick described above, but unfortunately it's not available on the web. If you're interested, I can send it to you (or anyone else who's interested) by email.

Answer (score -2):

My assembly knowledge is a little rusty, but it seems to me like `bitsearch` is overly complicated. How about just rotating the number to the right and counting the times you need to do that until it's zero?

Comment: I'm assuming there's a good reason to do it in assembly instead of C :)

Comment: I am sure there is a better way, but I still want to overcome this problem.

Comment: the algorithm you describe is exactly the algorithm that the OP used in his code... (although it may be optimized a bit)

Comment: oh poo. rustier than I thought, then.